# Aapt exited with code 11

Tags: android, aide-ide

Since yesterday my app is giving an error saying aapt exited with code 11.
I have done no changes from the previous time I opened the project
Just tried continuing the project and the error appears.
Searched the internet regarding the cause of the error but couldnt find anything.
What shall i do?
By the way i am using AIDE as my IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was receiving same error as you mentioned, aapt exited with code 11, I went into the Build & Run settings and refreshed the Maven repository, seems to have cleared up the cause of the error!

Answer (score 0):

I also find a case is the android.jar SDK version higher than your OS' SDK version.

Here's result I've tested.

Version name_Version code Int_Device name_Status

8.0_26_andorid26.jar_[The appointed SDK package.]

4.4_19_Nox AVD 5.0_aapt: exited with code 11

5.1_22_Vivo x6_aapt: exited with code 11

8.1_27_OnePlus 5T_[Success compiled.]